# warning: singleton variables error message in Prolog

Tags: prolog

The task here is to write a color map in prolog. Here is my code

```
/* Neighboring relationship*/
edge(wa, or). /* washington is a neighbor of oregon */
edge(wa, id). /* washington is a neighbor of idaho */
edge(or, ca). /* oregon is a neighbor of california */
edge(or, ne). /* oregon is a neighbor of nevada */
edge(or, id). /* oregon is a neighbor of idaho */
edge(id, mo). /* idaho is a neighbor of montana */
edge(id, wy). /* idaho is a neighbor of wyoming */
edge(id, ne). /* idaho is a neighbor of nevada */
edge(id, ut). /* idaho is a neighbor of utah */
edge(mo, wy). /* montana is a neighbor of wyoming */
edge(wy, ut). /* wyoming is a neighbor of utah */
edge(wy, co). /* wyoming is a neighbor of colorado */
edge(ca, ne). /* california is a neighbor of nevada */
edge(ca, ar). /* california is a neighbor of arizona */
edge(ne, ut). /* nevada is a neighbor of utah */
edge(ne, ar). /* nevada is a neighbor of arizona */
edge(ut, nm). /* utah is a neighbor of new mexico */
edge(ut, ar). /* utah is a neighbor of arizona */
edge(ut, co). /* utah is a neighbor of colorado */

/* Colors of the states*/
color(wy, yellow). /* wyoming is painted yellow */
color(wa, yellow). /* washington is painted yellow */
color(ne, yellow). /* nevada is painted yellow */
color(mo, green). /* montana is painted green */
color(ca, green). /* california is painted green */
color(nm, green). /* new mexico is painted green */
color(ut, red).   /* utah is painted red */
color(or, red).   /* oregon is painted red */
color(ha, red).   /* hawaii is painted red */
color(al, red).   /* alaska is painted red */
color(co, orange). /* colorado is painted orange */
color(ar, orange). /* arizona is painted orange */
color(id, orange). /* idaho is painted orange */


/*  adjacent rule*/
adjacent(X, Y) :- edge(X, Y); edge(Y, X).
connected(Node1, Node2) :- edge(Node1, Node2).
connected(Node1, Node2) :- edge(Node1, X), connected(X, Node2).

/*  miscolor rule*/
miscolor(S1, S2, Color) :-
    adjacent(S1, S2), color(S1, Color), color(S2, Color).

/* condition rule to test the miscolor rule */  
q :- miscolor(S1, S2, Color).
```

This is what bothers me most:
Write a rule called q :- condition. When testing, typing q will test your miscolor rule.

The code actually works but the compiler gives an error message:
question1.pl:62: warning: singleton variables [S1,S2,Color] for q/0.
Please help me with the last condition which causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

This warning is totally proper. From swi-prolog manual

```
A singleton variable is a variable that appears only one time in a clause
```

https://apps.nms.kcl.ac.uk/reactome-pengine/documentation/man?section=singleton

so you should correct the definition like below

```
q :- miscolor(_, _, _).
```

as your defining some variables which are not used anywhere.

If you would like to display all the miscolor pairs, you should just use sth like

```
miscolor(A,B,C).
```

Comment: That sounds great. I'd like to ask is it correct to not mention the states Hawaii and Alaska which have no neighbors in the /* Neighboring relationship and only assign a color to them?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting correctly what you want to do. You would like to remove/comment these two facts
```
color(ha, red).   /* hawaii is painted red */
color(al, red).   /* alaska is painted red */
```
?
If yes then I would leave them as these are true. Also, they would not impact performance at all, as the first predicate (of adjacent and color) you would invoke the adjacent predicate, so you would not even iterate over Alaska and Hawaii.

Comment: If not then please clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the messy question. The main task is to make so that no two neughbors have the same color. And what I wanted to ask above is 'Since Hawaii and Alaska have no neighbors is it enough to  just assign colors to them?' But I think you answered me even you didn't get what I tried to ask. Thank you.